# Questions on mov command in assembly

Tags: unix, assembly, nasm, cpu-registers

I have a few issues with using registers and storing data.

1. Before I read in a character I want a buffer of size 100 that the register **ESI** points to.
   Do I use this?

`mov esi, 100`  to store a buffer for size 100,
and then

```
mov esi, [al]
inc esi
```

to store the current character I entered into the esi and move it to the next location to store a new character?

I also can't find out how to properly check if a null terminated character is entered.
I've tried `cmp al, 0xa` to check for a new line
and `cmp eax, -1` to check eof.

Note: I have a function called read_char to read in a character to put into the **al** register

Comment: You are completely mixed up about everything here.  `mov esi, [al]` would use `al` as a pointer, and load 4 bytes from there.  Except that's impossible, you can't dereference 8bit registers.  Pointers are either 32 or 64b, depending on whether you're writing 32 or 64b code.  (`mov [esi], al` is a 1B store to the address stored in `esi`.)  You reserve space for buffers either on the stack by subtracting from `esp`, or statically in the bss section.  Google these things because the only possible answer to everything in this question is a full tutorial on x86 asm.

Comment: Also, `mov` is an instruction, not a command.  Commands are things you run from the command line, or put in shell scripts.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Not nececelery. I worked (in assembler) on a Ferranti Argus 500, built primarily for military applications - and they termed such objects "commands."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a buffer in NASM you can use `buffer times 100 db 0`

You get its address with `mov esi, buffer`

To store the character in `AL` in it, and raise the address write `mov [esi], al` `inc esi`

> how to properly check if a null terminated character is entered

The null would be the byte following the character. You need to compare a **word** for that. Read the character and the following byte, then compare:

```
mov ax, [esi]
cmp ax, 0x000A
```

This tests if linefeed was the last item in this zero-terminated string.